# Keeping Information from previous variables and outputs

Tags: java, list

Making a small program where I enter Word/s and it hashcodes turning it into numbers so I can use these numbers for the likes of seeds for games such as Rimworld or Minecraft.

What I currently use is:

```
String levelSeed= "hello";
int levelSeedNum = levelSeed.hashCode();
System.out.println(levelSeed);
```

Which works nicely. But I have been thinking about holding the Word/s and what the hashcode is in a List so I can see what I have already used. I cant seem to figure out how to do this as when I add a new Word/s it resets the list I have.

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add(levelSeed);
System.out.println(ls);
```

What would be the best way to not have the list reset every time I execute the code?

Comment: You could save your list in a file and retrieve it when you program is started. This is assuming you want to keep the list of previous runs. Otherwise, you might want to check out [MikaelF's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60574185/5784924)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you're assigning `ls` to a new list every time you have a new seed:

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This means that you lose whatever was in the old list. What you need to do is simply to initialize that list only once, and then add multiple elements to it:

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(); //this creates a new, empty list
//... do stuff
ls.add(aSeed);
//... do stuff
ls.add(anotherSeed);
//ls now has two elements in it
ls = new ArrayList<String>();
//and now it's empty
```

**EDIT**

If your want to build the list seed by seed, you'll need to do it in some sort of loop. Here's a simple example:

```
final int NUM_SEEDS = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEEDS; i++) {
    String seed = ... //collect a seed by whatever means you're using
    lst.add(seed);
}
//lst.size() is now NUM_SEEDS.
```

Comment: Is there a way I can "automate" it so instead of always needing to do ls.add(seed)? I assume it would involve some form of loop system that would add the new seed to the array

Comment: Exactly. I added a small example to give you an idea.